# Compiling Objective C Using Makefile

Tags: objective-c, makefile

Does anybody know how to compile Obj-C code using a makefile. Currently, I can get the code to compile and give me a unix executable but I don't know how to make an osx executable as It gives me the "Cannot run app because the classic environment is no longer supported" error when I try.

My current makefile is as follows:

```
CC = gcc
SOURCES=Src/OSX/main.m
FRAMEWORKS:= -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa -framework AppKit
LIBRARIES:= -lobjc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -arch i386 -g -v $(SOURCES)
LDFLAGS=$(LIBRARIES) $(FRAMEWORKS)
OUT=-o Build/main

all: $(SOURCES) $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(OBJECTS) $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OUT)

.m.o: 
    $(CC) -c -Wall $< -o $@
```

Comment: What is the output of running the command `file Build/main`?  What is the output of `make` when you run it?

Comment: don't set CC explicitly - let it come from the defaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is nothing wrong with your makefile. I used it with the following main.m file and it ran as expected.

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] init];
    fprintf(stderr, "Object: %s\n", [[obj description] UTF8String]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Object: %s\n", [[view description] UTF8String]);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, `file Build/main` yielded the expected result: `Mach-O executable i386`.

---

> "Cannot run app because the classic environment is no longer supported."

This error occurs when you are trying to run an Application that was built for Mac OS 9 or below, i.e. Apple's "Classic" Mac OS System. Are you sure you're not doing something a bit funky elsewhere (e.g. trying to use the deprecated Carbon API, etc)?

Comment: The makefile appears to be working and creating a Mach-0 however the "Cannot run app because the classic environment is no longer supported" error remains. Also, do you have any tips on removing or hiding the terminal as I am simply creating a Cocoa NSApplication yet the terminal remains. Sorry, I am rather new to Objective-C and Apple Development.

Comment: @MattDwarf That's probably worth another SO question - I come from a iOS background so I can't really help with Cocoa development, sorry.

Comment: You first need to create an NSApplication instance to have an interface with the WindowServer. This can simply be done by giving the instruction return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);